# Solving vector equations

Tags: vector

I made this very simple module to try and solve vector `X`:

```
Module[{a, b, x},
 a = {8, -2};
 b = {3, 3};
 Solve[x + a == b, x]
 ]
```

I get no output so I guess I am doing something wrong. Does anyone know how I can find the `x` and `y` value of vector `x`?

Comment: Maybe `x = {x1, x2};
a = {8, -2};
b = {3, 3};
Solve[x + a == b, x]` gives `{{x1 -> -5, x2 -> 5}}`

Comment: Really good solution, solves my problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Mathematica doesn't realise you want x to be a vector, so you have to tell it what you want more precisely:

```
Module[{a, b, x, y}, a = {8, -2}; b = {3, 3}; 
 Flatten@({x, y} /. Solve[{x, y} + a == b, {x, y}])]
```

This gives as output:

```
 {-5, 5}
```

Comment: Perfect. Exactly the answer I was looking for.