# How to represent arbitrarily dimensioned vectors in mathematica?

Tags: vector, input

I've seen [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/60793/solving-vector-equations) that vectors in Mathematica can be represented as lists.

I was recently trying to do the computation [`Solve[(a + (x-1)*b).b==0, x]`](https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/960f0c04-979d-43ea-83d7-d761fff0206b) where a and b are vectors and x is a scalar.

In order to do this, I had to predefine `a = {a1, a2, a3}` and `b = {b1, b2, b3}`.

Luckily, I knew my vectors were in three dimensions!

What should I do if I don't know how many dimensions my vectors are?

Comment: For this simple example, you could do: `Solve[TensorExpand[(a + (x - 1)*b).b] == 0, x]`.

Comment: @CarlWoll that works beautifully. Will it work in general?

Comment: @CarlWoll it doesn't look like that always works; if I do `TensorExpand[(a+bx)] /. Solve[TensorExpand[(a + (x - 1)*b).b] == 0,x][[1]]`, the result isn't useful. (It gives the same result without the first `TensorExpand`.)

Comment: Did you really use `a+bx` and not `a+b x` or `a+b*x`?

Comment: @CarlWoll Yes, I did. Thank you for catching that. (Still new to Mathematica...) With the multiplication sign it looks like it works. Thanks!